# Chrome extension default html or 404 (for single-page app routing)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-history

Our Chrome extension browser action opens a new tab:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
  url: chrome.extension.getURL('/html/main.html?route=/home')
})
```

main.html is a single-page app entry that uses the HTML5 history API (`history.pushState`) to change `/html/main.html?route=/home` to `/home`. This works, and navigation within the app works.

The only problem is that if the user refreshes the page `/home` will 404.

> This webpage is not found
>   ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Is there a way to make a default html or custom 404 that would redirect `/x/y/z` to `/html/main.html?route=/x/y/z`?

Comment: Any particular reason you are using a query param `main.html?route=/home` instead of a fragment `main.html#route=/home`?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it with [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) (untested!):

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if(/* condition on details.url */) {
      return {redirectUrl: fix(details.url)};
    }
  }, {
    urls: ["chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id + "/*"]
  }, [
    "blocking"
  ]
);
```

Note that you'll need `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking` permissions.

Comment: I wish those permissions were for our own extension URLs only :-(

Comment: They are! Since they are limited to what your extension can already access, [they don't generate any warnings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#nowarning).

Comment: For Angular will be the following code:
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    details => {
        const prefixUri = "chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id + "/";
        if(details.url.startsWith( prefixUri + "#/" )) {
            let newUrl = prefixUri + "index.html" + details.url.substr(prefixUri.length );
            return {redirectUrl: newUrl};
        }
    }
    , { urls: ["chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id + "/*"] }
    , [ "blocking" ]
);

Comment: @Mentor comments are not a good place for code; post a second answer!